# Get edited attributes in eloquent before update

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, revision

I have tried [Revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) to make revisions of my Eloquent models, 
but it doesn't work with one of my models named Person

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Person extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'persons';
}
```

Many people has experienced this problem , but it isn't solved yet.

Now i want to make something on my own.

Is it possible to get the old attributes before saving the new in this method?

```
Person::updating(function($person)
{

});
```

I want to make a revision table which stores the old attributes for the person table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Person::updating(function($person)
{
    $original = $person->getOriginal();
});
```